# Cannot find data type - error occurs only inside larger script

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, sqldatatypes, sql-server-2017

I am creating a UDF.
The function is successfully created **ONLY** if I run the `CREATE FUNCTION` block by itself.

If I include the `CREATE FUNCTION` block inside a much larger "complete" DB creation script, I get a weird error message stating an invalid data type was used.
(See code block and error screenshot below.)

`USE MyDB`, `SET ANSI_NULLS`, and `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` are identical in both cases, and have no effect.

This is very weird, because the UDTT is created much earlier in the DB creation script, with no errors. I can see the UDTT in SSMS, so it clearly exists ...

If I re-run the complete DB creation script, I obviously get a bunch of messages about recreating objects that already exist - I ignore these messages, because that's expected.
But then I get this error, which causes this particular function creation to fail, which blocks many other object creations after it.

If I drop the database, and re-run the complete database creation script, I receive no errors before this line, and I still receive the same error message about this datatype being invalid.

What could be causing this?
If I wanted to "repair" the complete DB creation script, where should I start?

```
USE MyDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Test_FloatToNString] ( )

RETURNS @TestResults TABLE (
                               [Category]      NVARCHAR ( MAX ) NOT NULL ,
                               [Example]       NVARCHAR ( MAX ) NOT NULL ,
                               [Expected]      NVARCHAR ( MAX ) NOT NULL ,
                               [Actual]        NVARCHAR ( MAX ) NOT NULL ,
                               [CaseSensitive] BIT              NOT NULL ,
                               [Tolerance]     NVARCHAR ( MAX ) NOT NULL ,
                               [Difference]    NVARCHAR ( MAX ) NOT NULL ,
                               [Passed]        BIT              NOT NULL ,
                               [Description]   NVARCHAR ( MAX ) NOT NULL
                           )
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @testData [NStringTestData] ;   /* Error here, see screenshot below */

    INSERT INTO @testData   /* etc. */
```

[image]

Here's what the UDTT looks like, in the complete DB creation script:

```
USE MyDB
GO

/* ... */

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[NStringTestData] AS TABLE(
    [Category] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Example] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Expected] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Actual] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CaseSensitive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Tolerance] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `MyDB` when you create `NStringTestData`, cause _user defined types_ are `defined at database level`.

Comment: @Sami Yes, I am sure. `USE MyDB` is in the creation script. And I can see the UDTT within the database. And the `CREATE FUNCTION` command is successful when isolated, only fails when used with the rest of the DB creation commands in a single combined script file.

Comment: Could it be that the schema in which the data type was created and your default schema are different? I'd suggest schema qualifying `[NStringTestData]` in any case.

Comment: @BenThul I'm only dealing with `[dbo]` at the moment, everything is in the same schema. I've heard this advice before, and I agree qualifying the schema everywhere is generally a good idea. But unfortunately, I did try that earlier today, and it made no difference to the behavior of this error.

Comment: Post the create script for your UDTT and I'll give it a try.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I edited the question to include the UDTT portion of the complete DB creation script.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me - obviously the script only had the create type and create function. I wonder if your function has an error in it? I only ask because the datatype of Tolerance is int in your datatype and nvarchar in your function return table.

Comment: Is the CREATE TYPE statement above/before the CREATE FUNCTION in the script?

Comment: @user5151179 Yes, all of the UDTs and UDTTs are defined at the very top of the script.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I wont ask you to post the whole script, I'll just assume it's too large and somewhat confidential.  If you don't get an answer by the time I do my next build, I'll write up an answer outlining how I'd go about debugging this sort of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugging method posted by user5151179 is very helpful.
Here's the post-mortem, which might help others narrow down the issue in similar situations.

This issue is caused by the DB script containing natively compiled functions/procedures being created before the problem function (which is *not* natively compiled, and does not reference any natively complied modules).

I still have no idea *why* this happens, but moving several dozen natively complied functions to a different "location" in the script (closer to the bottom, and most importantly *after* the creation of the problem function) completely resolved the issue, without modifying any of the functions or procedures.

Every object in the database is exactly the same as it was before, just created in a different order.

This baffles me, because there were no references between any of these objects, which would require them to be created in a specific order - and the error itself was simply a data type error, for a UDTT which was at the very top of my script, created literally before any other objects in the DB.

If anyone has any insight as to why SQL Server is so finicky about *when* natively complied functions and procedures are created, feel free to leave comments or post another answer.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it - very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to be a good answer, but here goes...

To debug this, I would load the full query up in SSMS, and add `BEGIN TRANSACTION` up the top.  On the next line put `-- ROLLBACK`.  When your query fails, you can roll back, and end up back at the clean state (empty db) with minimal trauma.

Basically just start deleting stuff that isn't required by the function where things are failing. Delete some DDL statements, test running and rolling back transactions as you go, until it runs without error.  When it runs without error, it is likely that the last chunk of code you deleted is causing your problem.

If you're deleting multiple DDL statements, which I would do, you can then get more granular at this point.  What I mean is, delete a whole pile of stuff that your function doesn't depend on, then run the whole query.  If it works, rollback, add that chunk back in (Undo/Ctrl Z) and then get more granular deleting smaller chunks, one at a time, until you're deleting single statements.

Treat it like a search.  When deleting a single DDL statement get your query to work, you've found the culprit.  You just need to find that statement.

With enough back and forth you should be able to identify a chunk of code, hopefully a single DDL statement, that is causing your issue.  If it isn't immediately obvious why that chunk of code is causing you grief, post it either here or in a new question and hopefully someone else will be more helpful than I am being.

Comment: +1 This is a very interesting, and effective, debugging method. I solved the problem before reading your answer, and this debugging method _could_ have led me to the "issue" more easily. I'm posting another answer alongside yours, because I have more specific details about the root cause, which may be helpful to others in similar situations.